# Replace button text with the text chosen from Dialog

Tags: java, android

I have a button that when it's clicked it brings up a single choice list dialog. After a choice is made in the dialog, I want the text currently on the button to change from (for example) "Select fruit" to the text the user chose in the dialog.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class PickFruitFragment extends DialogFragment {

private Button mPickFruitButton;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pickfruit, container, false);

    mPickFruitButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pick_fruit_button);

    mPickFruitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDialog(v);
        }
    });

    return rootView;

}


public void openDialog(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_fruit_title);
    builder.setItems(R.array.fruits_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();


}
```

}

Only thing I have in my XML right now is the button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/pick_fruit_button"
    android:id="@+id/pick_fruit_button"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp" />
```

Comment: Looks like you're well on your way. What's the specific problem?

Comment: I just wasn't sure what to do next to change the button text, but @Bruce's method worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
final String [] fruits = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruits_array);
builder.setItems(R.array.fruits_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        pickFruitButton.setText(fruits[which]);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```